# Oracle 12c Database V$session values

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c, oracle-rac

Why was I seeing more than the active no. of connections in V$SESSION view?
I am connected through SQL Developer and EM Express only but in V$SESSION its showing four connections with different SIDs.
But after some more time it came to two connections.
V$SESSION is dynamic View then why did it take that much time in update?

thanks

Comment: You can query the `USERNAME` and `STATUS` columns of `V$SESSION` table to get an idea if the information is for `ACTIVE`session only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you use such a query

```
select *
 from v$session v
where ( v.USERNAME not like 'SYS%' and v.USERNAME != 'DBSNMP' )
  and  v.STATUS = 'ACTIVE' 
order by v.LOGON_TIME desc;
```

to display *active* sessions, and perhaps your database is of ***RAC***(*Real Application Clusters*) type, and need to replace `v$session` with `gv$session` which shows more than one instances with `inst_id` column at the beginning of *the select list*.

Comment: Hey its giving only one SID of existing connection even if I am running it after opening new session with same user account but when I am selecting all from V$SESSION then its listing both SIDs. why?

Comment: @HamidAli didn't you try querying from `gv$session`, instead of `v$session` ?

Comment: @Barbarous gv$session instead of v$session is also giving only one sid however there are two active sessions.

Comment: @HamidAli what about commenting out this line  `--   and  v.STATUS = 'ACTIVE'`, i.e. are you sure whether the operation is `active`..?

Comment: @HamidAli you may even try `and lower(client_info) like lower('%'||'&cli_info'||'%')` or `and lower(module) like lower('%'||'&modul_name'||'%')` if client_info or module information is set( through application in most cases ).

Comment: Yes its showing as inactive after commenting but I don't know why its showing inactive?

Comment: @HamidAli `status` column shows whether the application currently interaction with database, it doesn't mean the app. is disconnected from db whenever it's `inactive`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your help.